# VNC viewer with multiple monitors

Tags: vnc, multiple-monitors, vnc-viewer

I am running a VNC server on Linux and a TightVNC viewer (ver.1.3.10 from 2/10/2009) on Windows with 2 monitors attached to it. I would like to have a full-screen session on both monitors at the same time, but whenever I do that, my full-screen always uses only one monitor.

Is it possible to extend the full-screen onto both local monitors? Perhaps there is a more modern version of a viewer that could make it work?

(In regular, not full-screen mode, it is easy - just run the VNC server with double desktop size and stretch the window on the local machine across both monitors. It's the full-screen mode that I cannot make work.)

Comment: Is it possible to share only one monitor from the server?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The free version of TightVnc viewer (I have TightVnc Viewer 1.5.4 8/3/2011) build does not support this.  What you need is RealVNC but VNC Enterprise Edition 4.2 or the Personal Edition.  Unfortunately this is not free and you have to pay for a license.

From the RealVNC website [releasenote] http://www.realvnc.com/products/enterprise/4.2/release-notes.html

```
VNC Viewer: Full-screen mode can span monitors on a multi-monitor system.
```

Comment: Thanks a million for your answer - I suspected but could not find anything... Would UltraVNC support something like this, or the only thing I could use is VNC Enterprise?

Answer (score 32):

Real VNC Viewer (5.0.3) - Free :

Options->Expert->UseAllMonitors = True

Comment: I believe this is the same as the answer of @RayFlush.

Comment: Under VNC View 6.20 it's not working like multi-monitor but just expanding resolution view on many monitors. So you are not going to get 2 monitors but one big with scrolling capability.

Comment: This helped me. I can go full-screen on both monitors. That said, I wish I could have two separate vnc sessions (a separate issue I need to fix). Because now, if I were to open a browser on one monitor on my client desktop, the whole vnc session goes to the background.

Answer (score 23):

RealVNC 5.0.x now offers a VNCViewer that will do dual displays on Windows without having to buy a license. (Licensing now covers the SERVER portion of their tools).

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I cannot choose you to be the "true" answer to the question as when it was asked, the person who is the current choice provided the best answer at the time... I did upvote yours, though. Thank you.

Comment: Does this require that the PC you are connecting 2 has 2 physical monitors?

Answer (score 4):

tightVNC 2.5.X and even pre 2.5 supports multi monitor.
When you connect, you get a huge virtual monitor.
However, this is also has disadvantages.
UltaVNC (Tho when I tried it, was buggy in this area) allows you to connect to one huge virtual monitor or just to 1 screen at a time. (With a button to cycle through them) TightVNC also plan to support such a feature.. (When , no idea)
This feature is important as if you have large multi monitors and connecting over a reasonably slow link.. The screen updates are just to slow..
Cutting down to one monitor to focus on is desirable.

I like tightVNC, but UltraVNC seems to have a few more features right now..

I have found tightVNC more solid.  And that is why I have stuck with it.

I would try both.  They both work well, but I imagine one would suite slightly more then the other.