# how to utilize 2 screens with vncserver?

Tags: centos, x11, vnc-server, vnc-viewer

I have 2 screens and I am connecting to a vncserver that's running on centos machine with a VNC Viewer (v5.2.1) from my windows laptop.
This opens a window that I can move from 1 screen to the other.
I would like the session to use both screens and by this I ***don't*** mean:

**(a)** 2 separate VNC sessions connected to 2 vncservers each on one screen

**(b)** 1 VNC window stretched on 2 screens

**(c)** Using something like Xming

The reason that I don't like the above workarounds is because with **(a)** I can't move windows from one session to the other and I also can't open eclipse on both of them (eclipse doesn't like running in two different instances).

With **(b)** it's very inconvinient since the screens are not perfectly aligned and every window that I try to maximize is maximized across both screens and I have to manually adjust my windows for each screen, not to mention stuff being annoyingly cut by the gap between 2 screens.

Workaround **(c)** gives me what I need in terms of working with screens but has one major downfall and its the fact that my sessions won't survive my laptop reboots (while with a vncserver working remote stable centos machine I can always connect to the same session).

Note that I am aware of the solution:

- Check "Full screen mode" in VNC Viewer > Options > Advanced > Display
- Set "UseAllMonitors" to True in VNC Viewer > Options > Advanced >
  Expert tab.

This gives me workaround **(b)** which is not what I look for.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The problem here is that VNC by design presents a single window on the client that embeds the whole desktop on the server.  The VNC client would have to detect which part of the screen is on which monitor and then pass that back to the backend so that the X server can know the monitor dimensions.  Likely the X server expects that this information is know when the X server start, rather than when the VNC client connects.  Moving the VNC client window would be the same as changing monitor dimensions.

Comment: this appears to be answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602985/vnc-viewer-with-multiple-monitors?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

[This is not an answer, just sharing a fix for an issue related to VNC full screen mode and multiple monitors]

ISSUE: With DisplayDevice set to 'DISPLAY 2' (it was set by default f or some reason), I was facing the following issue. When I maximize the VNC or check/uncheck 'pass special key to server' option, the VNC viewer would switch back to my laptop screen from my external monitor automatically. It was very annoying.

FIX: In DisplayDevice, don't hardcode anything. Use app perferences.

References:

https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006483577?page=1#comment_360001038057
https://help.realvnc.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002251297#server-displaydevice